# What is the difference between using a view inside a wrapper or directly with regards to view life cycle

Tags: swiftui

I have the following map wrapper view:

```swift
struct MapWrapper: View {
    @Binding var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
    }
}
```

and the content view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var region: MKCoordinateRegion = .init(...)
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
//      MapWrapper(region: $region)
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Bool.random() ? .green : .red )
                    .opacity(0.75)
                    .frame(height: 300)
            }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Using `Map` in the content view and moving it around, the overlay is rendered on every movement. Whereas if I replace the `Map` with `MapWrapper` and moving the `Map` inside of the wrapper around, the overlay is only rendered once.

Why is the behavior different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in behavior is due to the fact that in the first case, where `Map` is directly used in `ContentView`, the `Map` view is recreated every time its binding region changes. This is because `Map` is a struct and when one of its properties changes, a new instance is created.

On the other hand, when `Map` is used inside `MapWrapper`, the `Map` instance is created only once when MapWrapper is initialized. Subsequent changes to region do not recreate the `Map` instance, but simply update the `MKCoordinateRegion` value that it displays.

Therefore, when you move the `Map` around in the first case, it is recreated each time and the overlay is also redrawn each time. In the second case, the `Map` instance is not recreated and therefore the overlay is not redrawn.

By wrapping the `Map` view in a custom `MapWrapper` view, you can control when the `Map` instance is created and avoid unnecessary redraws of other views.